# Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No composer instance detected.' when updating carbon 1 to carbon 2

Tags: php, laravel

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No composer instance detected.' in E:\laravel\registrar\vendor\kylekatarnls\update-helper\src\UpdateHelper\UpdateHelper.php:326
Stack trace:
#0 E:\laravel\registrar\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Upgrade.php(124): UpdateHelper\UpdateHelper->setDependencyVersions(Array)
#1 E:\laravel\registrar\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Upgrade.php(148): Carbon\Upgrade::askForUpgrade(Object(UpdateHelper\UpdateHelper), true)
#2 E:\laravel\registrar\vendor\nesbot\carbon\bin\upgrade-carbon(28): Carbon\Upgrade::upgrade()
#3 {main}
  thrown in E:\laravel\registrar\vendor\kylekatarnls\update-helper\src\UpdateHelper\UpdateHelper.php on line 326
```

the above error is shown when trying to update carbon 1 to carbon 2.
I am using

- Laravel Framework 5.4.36
- PHP 5.6.35

composer.json

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^7.10"
},
"require-dev": {
    "composer/composer": "^1.10",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
```

Comment: What were your steps?

Comment: - > composer update
 -> ./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon

Comment: Can you show your `composer.json` ? I think you just need to put an appropriate version number and do a `composer update`

Comment: I don't see a carbon package in here.

Comment: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#installation